# Error: mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed

Tags: transactions, script, signature, broadcast

I have created a raw transaction from myElectrum wallet, but when I try to broadcast it I get this error:

```
mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed
```

Why is this happening?

The transaction is below:

```
01000000016e8e85990c3b55c2d0a309b4dbb58cf1ad1031875bd9787563‌c34e1e21747292010000‌006a47304402206b1a17‌596910f36633055f6562‌b86f203b04d328bd9d8a‌a972bfb28b43f88f6902‌2000aca8f00b8224cc1b‌35f4f73830d9043b58bb‌313f3f2fa9307c1498d9‌e29951012103604b96f0‌d94b08201f4c915f258d‌722c182a499c3f3da0bd‌fd90ea073ba8b0feffff‌ffff0320a10700000000‌001976a9143cc975a70f‌f7bc4e0a2be13f8e5f3‌57f5d5d2ec88ac400d03‌00000000001976a914cf‌e7d631b90268c07c26f3‌73ea9b08e091292a8788‌ac262bf4000000000019‌76a914f390899608bc92‌​46d5fd8554ad42127011‌​11a33a88ac00000000
```

Comment: Your transaction?

Comment: if we can see how the tx looks like, then we maybe able to help, but without references, it is quite difficult :-) Also: which version of Electrum are you using?

Comment: 01000000016e8e85990c3b55c2d0a309b4dbb58cf1ad1031875bd9787563c34e1e21747292010000006a47304402206b1a17596910f36633055f6562b86f203b04d328bd9d8aa972bfb28b43f88f69022000aca8f00b8224cc1b35f4f73830d9043b58bb313f3f2fa9307c1498d9e29951012103604b96f0d94b08201f4c915f258d722c182a499c3f3da0bdfd90ea073ba8b0feffffffff0320a10700000000001976a9143cc975a70ff7bc4e0a2be139f8e5f357f5d5d2ec88ac400d0300000000001976a914cfe7d631b90268c07c26f373ea9b08e091292a8788ac262bf400000000001976a914f390899608bc9246d5fd8554ad4212701111a33a88ac00000000

Comment: Here is the raw transaction I can't broadcast it..

Comment: what version of Electrum is used?